# Show message of confirmation

Tags: forms, primefaces, rendering

I want to display a message to confirm creation of a group but I cannot diplay it.

group.xhtml:

```
 <h:form id="grp">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2"> 

            <h:outputText value="Titre:"></h:outputText>
            <p:inputText value="#{gpeBean.titre}"></p:inputText>

        <p:commandButton  id="btn_save"
                     value="Créer"                             
                     actionListener="#{gpeBean.test}">
                      </p:commandButton>

                    </h:panelGrid>  
     </h:form>

        </center>
     </h:panelGrid>
      <h:form id="cr" rendered = "#{gpeBean.created}"> 
       <h:outputText value="#{gpeBean.message}"/>
     </h:form>
```

my bean :

```
@ManagedBean(name = "gpeBean")
@RequestScoped
public class GroupeBean implements Serializable{
GroupDAO daoGrp = new GroupDaoImpl();
UserDAO dao = new UserDaoImpl();
private String titre;
public String message = "";
private boolean created = false;

    public String test(ActionEvent event){
    Groupe p = new Groupe();
    p.setTitre(this.titre);
    daoGrp.Nouveau_groupe(p);
    created = true;
    this.setMessage("Groupe crée!");
    return "p1";
   }}
```

when I click button to execute method test, message is not displayed.

Comment: Did you try @Viewscoped ?

Comment: No I didn't. what's the meaning of update="@all"?

Comment: You are using `return "p1";` and `@RequestScoped`, try @Viewscoped ?

Comment: I've changed scope to @ViewScoped, I had an error saying :Error Rendering View

Comment: You would just like to show a message when group is created ?

Comment: yes I would like to show a message when group is created

Comment: You are using `actionListener`, so in bean code, the `return String` has no meaning !

Comment: Ok I will delete the return statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use @ViewScoped in your bean.

**Xhtml:**

```
<h:form id="grp">
       <h:panelGrid columns="2"> 
            <h:outputText value="Titre:"></h:outputText>
            <p:inputText value="#{gpeBean.titre}"></p:inputText>
            <p:commandButton update=":grp:cr" id="btn_save"
                     value="Créer"                             
                     actionListener="#{gpeBean.test}">
                      </p:commandButton>
       </h:panelGrid>  
       <p:outputPanel id="cr"> 
          <h:outputText rendered="#{gpeBean.created}" value="#{gpeBean.message}"/>
       </p:outputPanel >
</h:form>
```